# disable checkboxes in angular if checked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects represented as checkboxes, I want to disable the checkbox if its checked (it's value is set from the database)

```
<md-input-container ng-repeat="tab in allTabs">
                            <md-checkbox checklist-model="pop.tabs" checklist-value="tab" ng-disabled="disableCheckbox(this)">
                                {{tab.name}}
                            </md-checkbox>
                        </md-input-container>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.disableCheckbox = function (chk) {
        if (chk.isChecked)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

but this disable all checkboxes!

EDIT

I should use `chk.checked` instead, it works, but the problem is that once a checkbox is checked it's disabled, can I change this behavior?

Comment: Your data format is not clear. What does the `tab` object contains? what is `checklist-model`? `checklist-value`? Those are not standard directives...

Comment: I use this directive https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/
`tab` is just an object contains data like `name` `description` `dateCreated`, nothing special

Answer (score -2):

The reason that happens is that you are using a function for ng-disabled. Functions are checked in every digest cycle.

With that said, my advice is that in your tab object create a property "isChecked" and set it on ng-click and the ng-disable should stay something like:
ng-disabled = "!tab.isChecked".

Regards,